# How to show $\phantom{d}_d C_0+\phantom{d}_d C_4 + \cdots = 2^{d-2} + 2^{\frac{d}{2}-1} \cos(\frac{d \pi}{4}) $?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I want to show following identities

\begin{align}
  &\phantom{d}_d C_0+\phantom{d}_d C_4 + \cdots = 2^{d-2} + 2^{\frac{d}{2}-1} \cos(\frac{d \pi}{4}) \\
  &\phantom{d}_d C_1+\phantom{d}_d C_5 + \cdots = 2^{d-2} + 2^{\frac{d}{2}-1} \sin(\frac{d \pi}{4}) \\
 &  \phantom{d}_d C_2+\phantom{d}_d C_6 + \cdots = 2^{d-2} - 2^{\frac{d}{2}-1} \cos(\frac{d \pi}{4}) \\
 & \phantom{d}_d C_3+\phantom{d}_d C_7 + \cdots = 2^{d-2} - 2^{\frac{d}{2}-1} \sin(\frac{d \pi}{4})
\end{align}
Can you give me any hint or computation for this identities?

Comment: I think that these equalities can be proved using [series multisection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_multisection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

As the subscript of each subsequent binomial coefficient differ $4,$

If $x^4=1\implies x=\pm1,\pm i$

Set $x=\pm1,\pm i$ one by one in the following identity $$(1+x)^n=\sum_{r=0}^n\binom nr x^r$$

Find $$\dfrac{(1+1)^n\pm(1-1)^n\pm(1+i)^n\pm(1-i)^n}4$$

$1+i=\sqrt2\left(\cos\dfrac\pi4+i\sin\dfrac\pi4\right)$

$(1+i)^n=2^{n/2}\left(\cos\dfrac\pi4+i\sin\dfrac\pi4\right)^n=2^{n/2}\left(\cos\dfrac{n\pi}4+i\sin\dfrac{n\pi}4\right)$

Similarly, $(1-i)^n=2^{n/2}\left(\cos\dfrac{n\pi}4-i\sin\dfrac{n\pi}4\right)$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: can you give how to obtain cos and sin term in the process of (1-i)^n?  I think there are typos. $(1-i)^n$ in the third fraction be $(1+i)^n$,

Comment: @phy_math, Please find the updated version