# Calculate $\sum_{k=0}^\frac{n}{2}(-1)^k{n \choose 2k}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^\frac{n-1}{2}(-1)^k{n \choose 2k+1}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, summation

a) $\sum_{k=0}^\frac{n}{2}(-1)^k{n \choose 2k}$

b) $\sum_{k=0}^\frac{n-1}{2}(-1)^k{n \choose 2k+1}$

I think a way to calculate the sums is to see what happens to $(1+i)^n$
but after trying for 2 hours now I
still couldnt figure out what to do.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1605095/how-to-show-phantomd-d-c-0-phantomd-d-c-4-cdots-2d-2-2-fracd

Answer (score 2):

Your idea to examine $(1+i)^n$ is good. It is helpful to know that $$(1+i)^n=(\sqrt{2})^n\left(\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}n\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}n\right)\right)$$

Now assuming $n$ is even (since your expression uses $n/2$), looking at the real part:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}(-1)^k\binom{n}{2k}=\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^n\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}n\right)=\begin{cases}0&n\equiv2,6\mod8\\2^{n/2}&n\equiv0\mod8\\-2^{n/2}&n\equiv4\mod8\end{cases}$$

And assuming $n$ is odd (since your expression uses $\frac{n-1}{2}$), looking at the imaginary part:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}(-1)^k\binom{n}{2k+1}=\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^n\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}n\right)=\begin{cases}2^{(n-1)/2}&n\equiv1,3\mod8\\-2^{(n-1)/2}&n\equiv5,7\mod8\end{cases}$$

Comment: in second summation n is odd so can it be congruent to 0,2,4 or 6 mod 8, no right?

Comment: it will be congruent to 1,3,5,7 mod 8

Comment: @Prajakta Yes thank you. Copy-and-pasted the first block and did not read it carefully enough.